# Prevent Excel from scrolling all the way to the right when adding filters to column headers?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Whenever I add filters to all column headers in Excel 2010 and I have enough data to have to scroll horizontally, it jumps me all the way to the rightmost column. Whatever cell I had selected is still selected, so I can use the arrow key to get back to where I was, but it's still annoying. Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a macro the the Worksheet_Change event to do something about that, but it would probably be more annoying to have the sheet scroll everytime you do anything to it.